# How do I create a scheduled task, via command line, which includes advanced options

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a scheduled task (in WinXP) which runs every 10 minutes, starting at 16:00:00 to 06:00:00, daily, from the command line.

Currently, I can create a scheduled task which runs every 10 minutes, starting at 16:00:00, daily, by using the following command:

```
SCHTASKS.EXE /CREATE /SC MINUTE /MO 10 /TN "Scheduled task name" /ST 16:00:00 /SD 01/01/2000 /TR task.bat /RU SYSTEM
```

The question is, how do I modify the previous command so that it stops running at 06:00:00?

Comment: create a VB script and run that script from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I could find no way to modify the scheduled task from the command line.  As a work around, I pushed the responsibility of running the program every 10 minutes to my executable, leaving the scheduled task the sole responsibility of kicking off the program daily.

Answer (score 3):

Since there doesn't appear to be a command line switch for the stop time of a particular task, I think the best you can do is try setting up a task for the allotted time that executes this:

```
schtasks /delete /tn "My Task"
```

which should remove the task from the task scheduler, and cause it to stop executing.  I haven't tried this myself, so I don't know if it kills kittens or not.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx

Comment: Works fine. I've done the same thing before. Also, you can make another task that Re-schedules it with another start time. Effectivly letting you say `start at 16:00 and don't run anymore after 08:00`

Answer (score 3):

schtasks /change ... /disable can do this for Vista/7/2003.
xp does not support /disable
the task definitions reside in C:\WINDOWS\Tasks with the ".job" file extension
if you rename a ".job" file to something else such as ".bozo" it will not run
you can name it back to ".job" to restart it.